# What happens if the ground of a PCB touches the earth?

Tags: ground, esd, earth

I know that if an object is significantly more/less charged than another object and goes near it, an ESD can appear and then both objects would become balanced. This can happen when a human touches copper pads of a PCB for example.

Now let's consider an integrated circuit working on battery. The ground of the IC is different from the earth, so we cannot presume its potential, it can be anything. Is it possible for the ground to be charged to some kV when the PCB is rubbed against another object ?

Because if it is so, then, if the ground of the PCB touches the earth  (for example, the solder tip of a welding station touches a pad, or my finger with an anti-static wrist touches a component), an ESD can occur, right ? How to avoid this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The whole idea with ESD is to connect the device with another device at a point where a discharge is less likely to cause harm. The ground plane is most often a good place for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anti-static wrist has a 1 Megohm resistor. This will allow the potential to equalize slowly without any damage or spark. If you carry a PCB, and then you must place it on a grounded surface, touch the surface with your other hand before you set down the PCB. Don't let the PCB be the first thing to contact a grounded conductor. If you hand a PCB to another person, touch the person first (shake hands or fist bump or whatever), then transfer the PCB.

Soldering stations usually have anti-static mats, and you are supposed to wear the anti-static wrist band when you solder, also. So the PCB should be at earth potential prior to the soldering tip touching the work piece.

Comment: OK I get it ! So I have to wear the anti-static wrist which connects the objects I would touch to the earth through a 1 Mohm resistor, and then touch the ground of the PCB to eventually discharge it through the resistor.
Let's consider this situation : I touch the earth without any anti-static wrist. My potential would be the same as Earth. Then I touch the ground of the PCB without any anti-static wrist. If I understand correctly, I could still damage the PCB, right ? In that case, is touching earth before touching the PCB even usefull ?

Comment: Well, you are a resistor. So if one hand touches earth, and the other hand touches the PCB, the current will be limited. Also, the PCB by itself can only have a very small amount of surface charge accumulation. So there will not be much charge to equalize. The biggest danger to the PCB is when a person carries it. The person accumulates a large charge, and that charge is discharged through the PCB somehow. That is when you get damage. So any time you walk around carrying a PCB, you have to think of yourself as a charged up device. Discharge yourself before you set down or transfer the PCB.

Comment: Also, discharge yourself before you touch the PCB. Usually a PCB sitting on a table or bench will be pretty close to ground potential. Just discharge yourself before touching or transferring the PCB. I also try to first touch the PCB on a "GND" node of the PCB. Like the metal outside part of a USB connector or something like that.